# Spring-data-rest-jpa -> Query on elementCollection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring, Hibernate and JPA.

I got a book object like this:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
    private Set<String> keywords;
}
```

My repository looks like this:

```
public interface BookRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Book, Long> {
    @RestResource(path = "by-keyword", rel = "by-keyword")
    List<Book> findByKeywordsContainingIgnoreCase(@Param(value = "keyword") String keyword, Pageable pageable);
}
```

The queries I run always return 0 results.

Does anyone know where my error lay? 
Can I do this without a @Query annotation?

Comment: yes you can do that just create CustomBookRepository and put custom method in there after that create BookRepositoryImp which implements CustomBookRepository (default) and implement these custom methods in there.after that you can use with @Autowired spring will take this implementation as a default

Comment: I ment if i can do that with the method naming.

Comment: Your code actually looks right -- works as shown. See an example project I put together https://github.com/awgtek/spring-data-rest-book-example to show it working. Without more information, I can't say there are any errors. Note: tested on MySQL.